# ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Basic Compression

Tags: oracle, file, import, oracle-apex, dump

I have a dump file which is exported from Oracle 11G enterprise edition (Server1). Now, i'm trying to import the same dump file into oracle 11G express edition (Server2).

I'm getting many errors and looks like the following error is a root error.

```
ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"CCEFS"."CIP_USERS" failed to create with error:
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Basic Compression Failing sql is:

 CREATE TABLE "CCEFS"."CIP_USERS" (
 "RECKEY" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "USER_ID" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
 "NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
 "ADMIN" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
 "DISABLE" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N', 
 "CRE_DT" DATE DEFAULT sysdate, 
 "CRE_USR" VARCHAR2 (50  BYTE), 
 "UPD_DT" DATE, 
 "UPD_USR" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
 "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2 (4000 BYTE), 
 "GUEST_USR" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) DEFAULT
```

Could anyone help me on fixing the above issue? Also, please suggest the steps need to be followed while importing the dump file (exported from enterprise edition) into express edition.

Comment: [Basic compression is only available in Enterprise Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e47877/editions.htm#DBLIC116). What was the export command used, and can it be repeated with `compression=none`?

Comment: Take a look at https://community.oracle.com/thread/2408080?tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TRANSFORM` parameter to turn off compression on the import. This worked while attempting to import onto the Oracle version running in Amazon RDS

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-64FB67BD-EB67-4F50-A4D2-5D34518E6BDB.htm#SUTIL939

Answer (score 0):

Looks like compression and partitioning are enabled in your database. try setting it to NO and run .

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_TRANSFORM (handle => h1, name => 'TABLE_COMPRESSION_CLAUSE', value => 'NONE' );

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).